# How do I show how many members are in a member group?

Tags: query

I am creating a summary page that shows the number of members in each member group.

I tried the following but it only displays 1 as the result and there are 25 members in this group:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(*) as active_members from exp_members where group_id=9 "}
    {count}
{/exp:query}
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks.

Comment: use {active_members} instead of {count}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conflict of names of variables. "count" is a [reserved name](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/reserved_words.html#reserved-for-fields).

On all modules of EECMS, the current item number of a loop is parsed on the variable {count}, starting on 1. If you code a query that returns, let's say, 5 rows, your result would be "12345".

Your query returns just one row. The loop will be executed once and returns "1". Of course, you just need one row. You are already using another name. So use it:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(*) as active_members from exp_members where group_id=9 "}
    {active_members}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: It is also an option listed here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/#count

Comment: I gonna explain better.

Comment: Hi Robson, thank you for taking the time to explain that. Your solution works perfectly.